# What's the difference of Ignore Type in the Ignore Dialog of TortoiseGit?

Tags: tortoisegit

What's the difference of Ignore Type in the Ignore Dialog of TortoiseGit?

Ignore Type:
1.Ignore item(s) only in the containing folder(s)
2.Ignore item(s) recursively

If I right-click on a folder and  select one of the Ignore Type, the results are the same.
All folders and files in the selected folder will be ignored, including all subfolders.
Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

In the first cases the selected file(name) is only ignored exactly in the folder which it is located.

In teh second case you can say that files matching the file you selected is also ignored in all subfolders recursively. This is e.g. helpful for ignoring `*.tmp` files in all subfolders.

Comment: Please vote/accept this answer if it helped you or ask for forther information if you need further assistance.